# Maximum Perimeter of triangle in a Square

Tags: geometry

In square $ABCD$, the length of its sides is $5$.

$E$, $F$ are two points on $AB$ and $AD$ in such a way so that $\angle ECF = 45^{\circ}$.

Find the maximum value of the perimeter of $\Delta AEF$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say the $\angle ECB=\theta$ then $\angle DCF=45^{\circ}-\theta$. Now note that $AE=5(1-\tan \theta )$, $AF=5(1-\tan(45^{\circ}-\theta))$ and $EF=\sqrt{AE^2+AF^2}=5(\tan\theta + \tan(45^{\circ}-\theta))$ by elementary trig, the simplification for EF goes like this 
\begin{align*} 
EF^2&=AE^2+AF^2=5^2((1-\tan \theta)^2)+(1-\tan (45^{\circ}-\theta))^2)\\
&=5^2(2+\tan^2 \theta + \tan^2 (45^{\circ}-\theta) -2(\tan\theta+\tan(45^{\circ}-\theta)))\\
&=5^2(2+\tan^2 \theta + \tan^2 (45^{\circ}-\theta) -2\tan45^{\circ}(1-\tan \theta \tan(45^{\circ}-\theta) )) ,\text{using}\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A \tan  B}\\
&=5^2(\tan \theta + \tan(45^{\circ} - \theta))^2
\end{align*}

So perimeter of trianlge $AEF$ is always of $10$ now matter where $E$ or $F$ are on $AB$ and $AD$.

Comment: how EF = (AE^2 + AF^2)^1/2  ?????

Comment: Pythagoras theorem, angle A is 90

Comment: $AE+AF+EF≠10$. EF is wrong.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Why do you think it is wrong? Are you getting something else? I have added some explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know from second to third line.  I think that's wrong.

Comment: Don't think, start doing. I am using $\tan A + \tan B= \tan(A+B)(1-\tan A \tan B)$ as I mentioned.

Comment: you know tan45 is 1 right?

Comment: OK, I understood your answer, now, but previous answer was quite incomprehensive.

Comment: See I left details out on purpose. I gave the method and the answer, the OP was suppose to work it out. This is not a homework service.